# JS regular expression using which I want to split a string, but in one case keep the separator as well, but discard in other cases

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this regex to split a string

`(/\:|(#[0-9]*\s*)|\s*\|\s*|\s*\/\s*/)`

where it is for identifying a colon `:` OR an expression like `#1` OR a pipe symbol `|` OR a forward slash `/`.

case 1: in case of `:`, `/`, `|`, I want to split the string and remove these symbols as well.

case 2: in case of pattern `#12` I want to keep this pattern in the array also which we get after splitting

So eg I have string `#12 start|hello hi/bye : end`
the splitting function should give me an array like ['#12', 'start', 'hello', 'hi', 'bye'].

The problem here is using expression `(#[0-9]*\s*)` splits the array as I want, gives me the pattern in array, but also gives undefined in the array. Whereas using it without brackets like `#[0-9]*\s*` splits the array, doesn't give undefined, but also doesn't give the pattern #12 in the array.

PS: the example I quoted above is just to explain the context of the question.

Comment: I have already written the code, the expression to be precise, also have explained the output I am getting and its just not working properly I am asking help on that? It's explained clearly in the question @31piy

Comment: You can always just remove `undefined` and empty strings from the array after: `str.split(regexp).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: You can't want  `'hello', 'hi'` you seem to want `'hello hi'`

Answer (score 0):

Emtpy items in the resulting arrays will appear with this approach simply because that is how `split` works: once it finds a match, the substring before is pushed to the array *even* if it is an empty string. So, between consequent matches, you will always get these empty items.

You may use

```
/\s*(?:(#[0-9]+)|[:\/|])\s*/
```

and remove all empty strings with `.filter(Boolean)`:

```js
console.log(
 '#12 start|hello hi/bye : end'.split(/\s*(?:(#[0-9]+)|[:\/|])\s*/).filter(Boolean)
);
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/0jnt0Z/1).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `(#[0-9]+)` - Group 1 (will be added to output): `#` and 1+ digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[:\/|]` - a `:`, `/` or `|`
- `)` - end of the group
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Answer (score -1):

Try this pattern instead.

```
`#12 start|hello hi/bye : end`.split(/[^\w#]+/);
```

It basically splits string by sequences of non word characters except for `#`. This pattern is actually easier to read and modify.

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: That's the problem here on StackOverflow, nobody knows who's downvoting or why, for that matter

Comment: Yes, I agree. Downvoters should either leave a comment for suggesting improvements or even having their own answer for the issue.